# how to deserialize a Json to two lists in Apex?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I am passing the trigger.old & trigger.New values from the trigger to batch class through JSON. In the class while deserializing the JSON i am getting only one list. How can i get two lists(old & New). Below is my code..
In Trigger:

```
String paramsJSONString; 
 paramsJSONString = Json.serializePretty(trigger.old);
 paramsJSONString = paramsJSONString + ',' +Json.serializePretty(trigger.new);
```

In Batch Class desereilizing:

```
list<CustomObject__c> listOfRecords = new list<CustomObject__c>();
 listOfRecords (list<CustomObject__c>)json.deserialize(paramsJSONString, list<CustomObject__c>.class);
```

By this way i am getting only one list. How to get old & new separate lists.
Will this works for multiple records updations..?

Answer (score 4):

I think your approach is somewhat questionable, but from an implementation standpoint, here are a few options available to you.

1. Use `Queueable`, and you don't even need to serialize anything. You can instantiate the job with both lists.

For example:

```
public with sharing class MyCustomJob implements Queueable
{
    final List<SObject> oldRecords, newRecords;
    public MyCustomJob(List<SObject> oldRecords, List<SObject> newRecords)
    {
        this.oldRecords = oldRecords;
        this.newRecords = newRecords;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) { /* do stuff */ }
}
```

2. Serialize a `TriggerContext` object for later deserialization.

The structure would simply look like:

```
public class TriggerContext
{
    final List<SObject> oldRecords, newRecords;
    public TriggerContext(List<SObject> oldRecords, List<SObject> newRecords)
    {
        this.oldRecords = oldRecords;
        this.newRecords = newRecords;
    }
}
```

Then you can freely serialize/deserialize as needed:

```
// in trigger
TriggerContext context = new TriggerContext(trigger.new, trigger.old);
String data = JSON.serialize(context);

// in batch
TriggerContext batchContext = (TriggerContext)JSON.deserialize(data, TriggerContext.class);
```

3. Use a `List<List<SObject>>` for your serialization scheme.